# Importing Assimp: Assimp.xcodeproj Project Failed Build Error

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, assimp, cmake-gui

I am using the CMake gui to import assimp into my openGL project in Xcode. I am following the instructions here: [How to import assimp to my my Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359551/how-to-import-assimp-to-my-my-xcode-project)

However, my Assimp.xcodeproj does not build.

Here is the error message in Xcode:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('float (*)(const char *, const char *)' and 'nullptr_t')
```

(line 230, D3MFImporter.cpp)

Here is the warning I get in the CMake gui:

```
The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000037
The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000037
Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Looking for ZLIB...
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Found ZLIB: optimized;/usr/lib/libz.dylib;debug;/usr/lib/libz.dylib
Enabled formats: 3DS AC ASE ASSBIN ASSXML B3D BVH COLLADA DXF CSM HMP IRRMESH IRR LWO LWS MD2 MD3 MD5 MDC MDL NFF NDO OFF OBJ OGRE OPENGEX PLY MS3D COB BLEND IFC XGL FBX Q3D Q3BSP RAW SIB SMD STL TERRAGEN 3D X GLTF 3MF
Disabled formats:
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - found
Looking for pthread_create
Looking for pthread_create - found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.13.5 (Apple Git-94)") 
Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev):
  Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

   assimp

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Generating done
```

I am not exactly sure why there would be a syntax error since I am sure many people have used assimp without issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error has nothing to do with CMake, the problem is on C++ side.

Comment: @arrowd How is this possible? The file that has the issue was in the assimp folder.